# How to validate valid paypal id?

Tags: paypal, paypal-sandbox, server-side, rest

I am creating an android app which will be integrated to the paypal. I want to validate the email id provided by the user if its valid paypal id from the server side. I am unable to find any reference to validate valid paypal id. If their any REST api to achieve this or any function in the paypal android sdk, please tell me. Your help will be really appreciated.

Comment: Guess you are looking for Onboarding https://developer.paypal.com/docs/multiparty/seller-onboarding/before-payment/

Answer (score 1):

The only way to validate whether an email corresponds to an existing PayPal account is to have the user "Log in with PayPal" and look at the response details you get back with that API.

Integration document: https://developer.paypal.com/docs/log-in-with-paypal/integrate/

Try the button generator in Step 4 as opposed to doing it manually.

Comment: what should i type in the redirect_url as i am calling this api in the android app through retrofit

Comment: Some deep link to your application.